# So what does Microsoft CLR actually do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, clr

Correct me if I'm wrong. From what I get CLR combines multiple supported language compiled sources, right? So that means I can write UI and the connection to the database in VB and the logic in C# for example? And if I'm right, how to do it in Visual Studio?

Comment: You create an empty solution in VS. Add a new C# project to it. Add new VB.NET project to it. Add reference of one project to another and there you go. That's how you do it.

Comment: So I understood right to CLR part?

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . What is your underlying problem?

Comment: It's not a problem asking for a solution, I'm just making sure I understood tight about CLR